# Changing out ceiling light fixture and found no box, - how to proceed?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling, old-house, knob-and-tube

I am replacing a ( *hanging* ) ceiling fixture in the dining room and found only wires and no box ( *see photos* ).

There's no junction box and the wires are old and gnarly looking. The house was built in 1900, and while I believe most of the electrical has been redone, there may still be knob and tube in the ceiling.

The other fixture I just replaced in the living room had same old wiring, but a plastic box was there so it seemed fine. This looks dangerous to me, but would love to hear what you all think.

Is it just a matter of putting a box up there and pulling the wires through ?

Fixture requires a rating of 75C, is this wiring safe? Or do I need to get a pro ?

Happy to provide more pix if that's helpful. Thanks in advance.

[image: ceiling fixture hole]
[image: ceiling fixture 2]
[image: ceiling fixture hole]

Comment: Are you sure there is not a box, i see the curved edge of a metal something but it is difficult to see.

Comment: Yeah, looks like someone put drywall over plaster at some point, so the box is recessed somewhat.

Comment: Pretty sure -- are you talking about on the left side of the first photo? That's the cable, it's got a white marking along it

Comment: It is still too dark inside there, Is there a joist near the wires you can attach a pancake box to ? Is there space in there ? Is there play in the wires ?

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to get a great picture. There's hardly any space at all, and very little give to the wires. There appears to be a wood layer behind (on top of) the plaster layer that's kind of striated-looking -- you can see it best on the right side of the 3rd photo. The cable looks it's running through a hole drilled through that. The old fixture, which was about 35 pounds, was being held up by two long screws straight into the ceiling (you can see in pic 1) so there must be something solid behind those holes.

Comment: At the very least,  definitely put in a plastic box.  I would avoid metal because you don't want to give the illusion of a ground being available there.  Mount the box to whatever joist or support the "two long screws" went into.

Comment: Thanks @CarlWitthoft. Any concern about heat resistance for that wiring? Safe to use a 75C fixture?